# HOW TO call the JAVASCRIPT function on submit

Tags: javascript, jquery

Following is my javascipt function which i want to call when user click on submit kindly let me know how can i make that call????

```
    <script type='text/javascript'>
    $(document).ready(function(){

  function(e){

                //stop the form from being submitted
                e.preventDefault();
}
    </script>


<input class="bttonn1" type='submit' onClick="" id='send_message' value='Send The Message'>
```

Comment: You don't have a form or valid JavaScript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `submit` event on the `form` element, not `click` on the submit button.

(And your code is incomplete, you're missing the closing `}` on the handler function, the closing `);` on the call to `click` [which you'd change], the closing `}` on the `ready` handler, and the closing `);` on the call to `ready`.)

Comment: I MISTAKENLY UPLOADED THE CODE WITH SOME ERRORS KINDLY SEE NOW AND LET ME KNOW HOW CAN I CALL THE FUNCTION??\

Comment: issue is being resolved i was getting errors because of not including <!--<script type='text/javascript' src='ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/…; <script type='text/javascript' src='js/jquery-1.3.2.min.js'></script>

Comment: @FaizanQadri: Ah, yes, you do need to be sure to include jQuery before using it. :-) (1.3.2 is very old, though, and be sure you only include it once.)

Answer (score 0):

Just like this: http://jsfiddle.net/joeflateau/9c2Fm/

Listen for `submit` on the form and `preventDefault` that

Comment: issue is being resolved i was getting errors because of not including 

<!--<script type='text/javascript' src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js'></script>-->
<script type='text/javascript' src='js/jquery-1.3.2.min.js'></script>

Answer (score 0):

If it's just a button then you can just use functions from within the onclick method:

```
<input class="button1" onClick="sumbitForm()">
<script type="text/javascript">
function submitForm() {
//Your code here
//If you need to get anything from within a form try using document.getElementById(string)
}
```